# Grammatical name for BEFORE HE COULD REACT

Tags: meaning

> The man was instantly awake, but *before he could react,* I had snatched the crutch and escaped with it.

In this sentence,  what is the grammatical name for **before he could react**?

Comment: Do you mean what's a one-word alternative?

Comment: Grammatical name for it

Comment: I would thank you to format your post so it's more legible.

Comment: I guess you could call it a _temporal adverbial clause_, but I would focus on spelling (_i_?) and basic conjugation (_escaping_?) before diving into such grammatical details.

Comment: Internally it is a preposition phrase; externally it is an adjunct to the clause *but I had &c*.

Answer (score 3):

I think the peculiarity that's being referred to in the sentence is the fact that *before he could react* presupposes that he did **not**, in fact, react. In other words, *before* is negative in this construction, and denies the clause it introduces.

This particular construction has been well-documented and is called the ***Counterfactual*** use of *before* in the literature. It often uses *can* or *could* to emphasize impossibility, but that's not necessary, viz:

- *Get him out of here before anybody sees him.*
  (Note the [negative polarity item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) *anybody*, triggered by Counterfactual *before*)

Success in the endeavor could be reported as

- *We got him out of there before anybody saw him.*
  (which  entails that nobody saw him)

Comment: You should have been a prospector.

Answer (score 0):

Like a comment said, and according to sources such as these:

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/sentence-structure

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_clause

It seems most likely to be classified as **an adverbial clause**. A temporal adverbial clause, because it gives time information. It is a clause because it contains both a noun phrase and a verb phrase ("he" and "could react"), and it is adverbial because "before" is an adverb, and the clause as a whole plays an adverbial role (it gives precision on when the events of the clause "I had snatched" happen).